# bad access after NSUserDefault synchronize

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a UITableView with some data. Every cell has a button and if you press it you delete the cell selected. After that I have to save my data with NSUserDefault. Here some code:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{   
    int tag=sender.tag;
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:tag];

    [self saveData];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];  
}
```

the `buttonPressed` method calls `saveData` method:

```
-(void)saveData{
    dataString=[[NSString alloc]init]; //defined in .h file

    for(int i=0; i<([myArray count]); i++){
        ClassObject *aObject=[[ClassObject alloc]init];
        aObject=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:aObject.idObject];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:aObject.description1];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:aObject.description2];
        dataString=[dataString stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
        [aObject release];
    }


    NSUserDefaults *dataDefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [dataDefault setObject:dataString forKey:@"myDataString"];
    [dataDefault synchronize];
    [dataString release];
}
```

in debug mode everything goes fine until the `saveData` method ends. When it ends the debug returns on `buttonPressed` method, it reloads the tableview and then the app crashes. And I don't know why.

Some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: does it crash on any line of code that you're listing up there? on the "`reloadData`" line or right after returning from the "`buttonPressed`" method?

Comment: Maybe you should post your datasource delegate code, it looks like that's where the crash is happening.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann it crashes after the method "buttonPressed" is finished. just after the last '}'

Comment: @gabboSonc Your question has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode at all, removed inappropriate tag.

Comment: @gabboSonc: Did you check your code with the Static Analyzer (Product -> Analyze) ? That should point out most of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does `aEquipaggio` come from in your `saveData` app? Why are you releasing it in each iteration of the loop? That doesn't make sense and it's very likely over-released, causing the crash later.

*Edit:* Now that you changed the code in your question, `aEquipaggio` is no longer there, but the `release` at the end of the loop is still incorrect, and the first line in the loop is entirely pointless (and leaks) because you never use the `ClassObject` instance you allocate.

You also shouldn't be releasing `dataString` at the end of the method. At that point, `dataString` no longer contains the same instance that you `alloc`-`init`ed at the beginning because you've replaced it with an autoreleased instance in the loop. (`[[NSString alloc]init]` is pointless anyway, just use `@""`).

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassObject *aObject=[[ClassObject alloc]init];
aObject=[arrayEquipaggio objectAtIndex:i];
// ...
[aObject release];
```

[Firstly, and most importantly, it's rather `anObject`.](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)

Secondly, this both leaks memory (you lose the pointer to the allocated instance when you re-assign `[arrayEquipaggio objectAtIndex:i];` to the variable) **and** over-releases `aObject` (which now, as I just explained, points to an object within the array, so you are releasing an object you don't own).

All in all, remove the line with the alloc-init and that with the release (you make the very same mistake with the `dataString` variable too) and:

***[Read this before continuing with development!](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)*** Else you will have serious trouble doing anything in Objective-C. Currently you seem to have no idea about how memory management works. (It would also be worth to learn C before trying to use Objective-C, but unfortunately that turns out to be too big an expectation...)

Comment: thanks but i could name it aobject or bobject or cobject. the 'a' is not an article

Comment: @gabboSonc OK, then the rest of the answer still applies (and anyway a better naming convention would be `objectA`, etc. in this case), you have to take care of the pointers so you don't leak and overrelease objects.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got the memory allocation wrong. This is what you’re doing:

```
dataString = [[NSString alloc] init];
dataString = [dataString stringByAppendingString:@"$"];
[dataString release];
```

First you allocate a new string that you have to release later. That’s OK. Then you store a different pointer into the `dataString` variable, leaking the previous string. And then you release the autoreleased string created by `-stringByAppendingString`, so that the object gets over-released soon after that.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, maybe it has something to do with the releasing of the `dataString`. Try optimizing it.